# Need a regex that will give me pagepath without domain

Tags: regex, excel, ms-word

I been trying to use `regexextract` in docs (or excel) to get the pagepath of a url - like what is after the tld.

example `http://google.com/this-folder/this-page-is-here`

I just want it to extract `/this-folder/this-page-is-here`, but so far I can only get `this-page-is-here` or `/this-folder` seperately.

Sorry I'm not too good with regex can anyone help me out?

This is what I've tried

```
=regexextract(A1; "\//*\/*.*\/(.*)")
```

which returns `this-page-is-here`

But I've been trying it so long I don't even understand life anymore can someone show me how you're supposed to do this?

Comment: `"//.+?(/.*)"` should work - the `?` makes the dot non-greedy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"//.+?(/.*)")
```

Tested working - You need to add the `?` to make the `.+` non-greedy (stop matching ASAP)

Taking your version and adding the `?` fixes it as well (I also removed an extra `/` at the beginning)

```
=regexextract(A1; "//.*?/(.*)")
```

Comment: Thank you even more than the previous guy. I've been doing it so long I forgot everything I knew. That works great! I'll come to you next time I've got a problem hah!